# Extracting information from column after regexp match in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, match

I have following column (col) in postgres table.

```
col
uniprotkb:Q92843(protein(MI:0326), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
intact:EBI-4392836(peptide(MI:0327), -1 - In vitro)
chebi:CHEBI:132213(small molecule(MI:0328), -2 - Chemical synthesis (Chemical synthesis))
dip:DIP-24261N(protein(MI:0326), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
reactome:R-HSA-2089970(stable complex(MI:1302), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
refseq:NR_131157(lncrna(MI:2190), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
rnacentral:URS00004A7003_9606(rna(MI:0320), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
signor:SIGNOR-C173(stable complex(MI:1302), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
uniparc:UPI0000073D6C(protein(MI:0326), 9606 - Homo sapiens)
```

I am applying regexp_match function on this column to extract following information.

Desired columns are:

```
col1       col2    col3     col4     col5
uniprotkb  Q92843  protein  MI:0326  Homo sapiens
intact     EBI-4392836  peptide  MI:0327 In vitro
chebi      CHEBI:132213 small molecule  MI:0328  Chemical synthesis (Chemical synthesis
dip        DIP-24261N   protein   MI:0326   Homo sapiens
reactome   R-HSA-2089970  stable complex  MI:1302   Homo sapiens
refseq     NR_131157      lncrna   MI:2190   Homo sapiens
rnacentral URS00004A7003_9606  rna  MI:0320  Homo sapiens
signor     SIGNOR-C173     stable complex  MI:1302  Homo sapiens
uniparc    UPI0000073D6C   protein  MI:0326   Homo sapiens
```

I have applied following regex on this column:

```
regexp_match(col, '^[^\:]+') )[1]::varchar AS col1,
regexp_match(col2, '(^[^:]*:\s*)(.*)\(.*') )[2]::varchar AS col2
```

I am getting following columns after match:

```
col1    col2
uniprotkb  Q92843(protein
intact     EBI-4392836(peptide  
chebi      CHEBI:132213(
dip:DIP-24261N(
reactome:R-HSA-2089970(
refseq:NR_131157(
rnacentral:URS00004A7003_9606(
signor:SIGNOR-C173(
uniparc:UPI0000073D6C(
```

I am escaping the parenthesis but still getting them in col2.

Any suggestions here would be really helpful

Comment: `col` values always have same pattern, as you show in question  ?

Comment: @OTAR There are additional distinct column values (added now in the post). But the pattern is same in all the column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second column, you could just as in the first pattern use a negated character class `([^()]+)` matching any char except a `(` or `)`

The reason you match too much is that the `.*` is over matching and will backtrack until the last occurrence of `(` in the string.

You could use a non greedy version `.*?` but the negated character class is a bit more efficient.

```
(^[^:]*:\s*)([^()]+)\(.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rsdEHm/1)